# SVG icons on a round circle side by side another div, Bootstrap 4.5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, bootstrap-4

I started to get into Bootstrap 4.5 and SVG for icons. I'm having a tough time understanding how it works atm. I want to place the SVG inside a shape (rounded-circle) for now. But would like that shape to be side by side another div. I can't move the div to place them on the same line. Following is a code snippet.

```css
.svg-icon {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 14px);
  left: calc(50% - 14px);
}

.poll-icon-container {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="rounded-circle poll-icon-container text-success">
  <svg
    width="2em"
    height="2em"
    viewBox="0 0 18 18"
    class="bi bi-box-arrow-in-up-right svg-icon"
    fill="currentColor"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    <path
      fill-rule="evenodd"
      d="M14.5 3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 13 1.5H3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5 3v5a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v10a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h4a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5V3z"
    />
    <path
      fill-rule="evenodd"
      d="M4.5 6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6.5H5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"
    />
    <path
      fill-rule="evenodd"
      d="M10.354 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-8 8a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l8-8a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z"
    />
  </svg>
</div>
<div>
  should be on the right side of the icon 
</div>
```

Comment: `div{display:inline-block}`? `body{display:flex}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are using Bootstrap, lets cover those 2 `div`s in one parent `div` and make them [display flax in bootstrap way](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/)

`d-flex` - BS class to make block to `display: flex;`

`justify-content-start` - BS class to make `justify-content: flex-start;`

`align-items-center` - BS class to make `align-items: center;`

`ml-3` - BS [sizing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/) class, `margin-left: 1rem;`

```css
.svg-icon {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 14px);
  left: calc(50% - 14px);
}

.poll-icon-container {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center">
  <div class="rounded-circle poll-icon-container text-success">
    <svg width="2em" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 18 18" class="bi bi-box-arrow-in-up-right svg-icon" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path
      fill-rule="evenodd"
      d="M14.5 3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 13 1.5H3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5 3v5a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v10a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h4a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5V3z"
    />
    <path
      fill-rule="evenodd"
      d="M4.5 6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6.5H5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"
    />
    <path
      fill-rule="evenodd"
      d="M10.354 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-8 8a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l8-8a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z"
    />
  </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="ml-3">
    should be on the right side of the icon
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works. thank you! im a little new to flexbox. ill have to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Add inline css with **position: absolute;** check below snippet.

```css
.svg-icon {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 14px);
  left: calc(50% - 14px);
}
.poll-icon-container {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="rounded-circle poll-icon-container text-success"   style="display:inline-block;">
                <svg
                  width="2em"
                  height="2em"
                  viewBox="0 0 18 18"
                  class="bi bi-box-arrow-in-up-right svg-icon"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path
                    fill-rule="evenodd"
                    d="M14.5 3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 13 1.5H3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5 3v5a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v10a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h4a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5V3z"
                  />
                  <path
                    fill-rule="evenodd"
                    d="M4.5 6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6.5H5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"
                  />
                  <path
                    fill-rule="evenodd"
                    d="M10.354 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-8 8a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l8-8a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z"
                  />
                </svg>
              </div>
              <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left:10px;line-height: 50px; position: absolute;">
                should be on the right side of the icon 
              </div>
```